# Can you inherit the version from the parent POM in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, project

I have a bunch of projects like:

```
project1
project2
project3
........
project111
```

Each project compiled in jar: project-1.1.1.1.jar, ....
Does it possible in parent folder add pom.xml so I can define version 1 time for all projects?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you omit `<version/>` it inherits from the parent. However, the `<parent/>` element must contain a `<version/>` for the parent, so the version must occur in every single POM, but only once.

Comment: You still have to specify the (parent) version number in the child pom...

Answer (score 25):

You can do this:

```
parent pom.xml:
<project>
  ...
  <version>${my-project-version}</version>
  ...
  <properties>
    <my-project-version>1.1.1</my-project-version>
  </properties>
</project>

child pom.xml:
<project>
  ...
  <parent>
    <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    <version>${my-project-version}</version>
  </parent>
  ...
</project>
```

At least, this works for me.

Comment: But do you then set `my-project-version` on the command line with `-D`?

Comment: I didn't, if I remember correctly. But it does need parent to be already checked out in the correct relative path.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work at all with Maven 3.0.4

Comment: this seems to be addressed in maven 3 with `[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant.`

Comment: Intellij IDEA's mvn doesn't understand that, but works smoothly in command line.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a problem in IntelliJ anymore, or in mvn 3.3.9. Also, I didn't need to specify `<relativePath>`, if that matters (I never had it in my submodules' poms).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Your solution works only if you have to build a project with submodules that will not be used by other projects, otherwise you'll get errors when dependencies are resolved. If you do a  `mvn install`, Maven creates a pom for each submodule with `${my-project-version}` as version instead of the actual version.

Comment: To get the actual version in the pom file, you can follow the details here:  https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Answer (score 7):

Using a property and referencing it works... unless you are using the release plugin to do releases in which case it removes "-SNAPSHOT" from the version and automatically replaces all instances with the real version number - which overwrites any replacement variables you've set.  You may be better off just setting it in each POM and using the release plugin to tag, increment, and release your project.