# Replacing variables when packaging the pom.xml into JAR

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin

I have a Java Maven project with several modules. When referencing to the parent module from the individual modules, the following information is added to project `A\module-sample-app\pom.xml`:

```
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>module-sample-app</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>module-sample-app</name>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>sample-app-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-${buildLifeId}</version>
    </parent>
```

The parent application `A` has the following entry in `A\pom.xml`:

```
   <artifactId>A</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>A</name>
   <version>1.0-${buildLifeId}</version>
```

To run the build, the following is executed on the parent directory of project `A`:

Example: `mvn clean install -DbuildLifeId=1001`

The JAR file generated has an embedded `pom.xml` with string `${buildLifeId}` and not the value `1001`.

When trying to use on the module `sample-app` in another application, `B`, as the runtime variable was not replaced with the actual value, it is failing to fetch the dependency. Just to highlight, `B` is not a module of `A`.

In `B\pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-sample-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-1001</version>
</dependency>
```

With this dependency, as the `pom.xml` embedded within the `module-sample-app-1.0-1001.jar` would have the parent version defined as `<version>1.0-${buildLifeId}</version>`, the dependency fails to load.

So my questions is - does Maven support a plugin that can replace the run time variables before packaging the `pom.xml` into the JAR? Or is there a workaround. Can I use Ant plugins to replace the `buildLiefeId` variable in the version node to actual value when JAR is built?

Comment: Is it primarily for the version number in the jar file that you're doing this?

Comment: Yes, for the version number alone. When I try to add a dependency on this module in a completely different application (Say App-B), since the pom.xml has a variable which doesn't get replaced, the dependency isn't resolved in the new application (App-B).

Comment: See also [Maven project version inheritance - do I have to specify the parent version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10582054/1744774).

Comment: Thanks @Gerold. I tried to rewrite the question to make it more detailed around the problem am facing.

Comment: You can do that but you have to use `${revision}` or `${sha1}` or `${changelist}` and use it with care see the documentation https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html Furthermore if you really use something `1.0-1001` you have created a release which seemed to be more related to a SNAPSHOT version instead.  You have to use Maven 3.5.0+ (best would be to use Maven 3.5.4)...

Comment: @khmarbaise, yes that is what am looking for. Thank you. Let me try it out, not sure if our repositories have 3.5.0+ as we are still at a lower version. But this is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I strongly recommend to use the most recent version of Maven...

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem. I get a similar error: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven:module-sample-app:jar:1.0-1001: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:sample-app:jar:${revision}${changelist} from/to central . It is still unable to replace the ${revision} on the pom.xml which is embedded within the module-sample-app.jar

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for informing about the ${revision}. It helped with so many other projects.

Answer (score 1):

I was already using `${revision}` - I just had to use the Maven Flatten plugin in both the parent and child poms to fix this issue.