# How to read pom version from file

Tags: maven, maven-3

Our project has six maven projects all these are independent projects. And each project has  its own sub modules. But we are maintaining same pom version for all these independent projects and every time we are replacing the same pom version in all these projects. I want to read the pom version from some common file which should reflect in all these projects if pom version changes. Can you please let me know how to do this.

Comment: Check out answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582054/maven-project-version-inheritance-do-i-have-to-specify-the-parent-version

Comment: You say "every time we are replacing the same pom version in all these projects" - do you mean for every release? Do you have each project on its own versions for development and then do an alignment for a cross-project release? Or do you mean you set the version for every change in every project?

Comment: Hi Ryan,  We are changing pom version in every project for every release

Comment: Can you please show the directory structure and give some examples how your pom files are looking?...and simple answer is: you can't read it from file..