# Is it possible to add a check that all submodules have the same version defined as in parent pom?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a project with numerous submodules.

In each submodule `pom.xml` file, I repeat exactly the same version number that was defined in parent `pom.xml` file.

Is it possible:

- to define version number in smart way, in only one place, in only one `pom.xml` file?
- to add some verification during build phase that all of the `pom.xml` files have exactly the same version defined?

Answer (score 0):

For 1: This might be of help
[Maven project version inheritance - do I have to specify the parent version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582054/maven-project-version-inheritance-do-i-have-to-specify-the-parent-version/51969067#51969067)

For 2: You may think of writing your own maven plugin and injecting it with the maven lifecycle.
Please refer to: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/